Are there different versions of Mozart's Ave Verum Corpus?
I have a photo copy of the sheet music for Mozart's Ave Verum and it seems that it is slightly different from other sheet music I found on the internet.
This part specifically:

For the bass part, the above has two half notes, while everywhere else I see this:

Unfortunately I do not know the name of the book where the first version is from. Can this be a mistake in my copy, or are there multiple versions of Mozart's Ave Verum? The performances that I saw on youtube follow the second version with a pause and two quarter notes.

The explanation that this is simply a keyboard reduction of the string parts with the words applied does not stand up to the fact that, in the following phrase, two measures after the discrepancy that is the subject of the question, the tenor part in the keyboard reduction shown in GratefulDisciple's answer follows the viola part rather than the choral tenor part.  Namely it has a quarter rest followed by three quarter notes, A, G♯, B, whereas the score in the question has a half rest followed by a single half note, D.
A more likely explanation is that the version shown in the question is arranged for performance without accompaniment, and that the arranger chose to modify the bass part in that measure by having it follow the orchestral bass instead of the original choral bass.
The reason for doing this there is that the chord on the downbeat is in first inversion, meaning the bass has the third of the chord.  But the choral bass has a rest there; it is the orchestral bass that carries the third of the chord, and without an orchestra or organ (or other keyboard) playing the accompaniment, you are left with a bare fourth, the tenor on B and the soprano and alto in unison on E.  This interval has generally been proscribed for most of the history of counterpoint, or rather treated like a dissonance that must be resolved a certain way, and this fourth isn't resolved that way (because the B isn't the true bass note).
If this is the reason, the arranger's name should be noted on the first page.  However, it seems that this adaptation dates back at least to 1883 or perhaps 1868 (Sammlung von Volksgesängen für den gemischten Chor (Ignaz Heim), though that has a different rhythm of a half-note G♯ slurred to a quarter note E, so it is more similar to the original), so it may be that the editor of the edition shown in the question took it unawares from some other secondary source.
The 1835 Orpheus: Sammlung auserlesener, mehrstimmiger Gesänge ohne Begleitung has a different solution to the problem; instead of a G♯ half note followed by an E, the bass has two E half notes.  There's still no third in the chord until the second beat of the measure, but this solution also avoids the improper unsupported perfect fourth.

One good way is to check whether a classical score we find on the Internet (or a photocopy from somewhere) is authentic is through investigating a list of editions in IMSLP, which usually includes holograph manuscript, first editions, etc.
The 1st image seems to be coming from a piano/choir reduction/adaptation, but your 2nd image can be verified to be the Bass vocal part of the original manuscript.  See the holograph manuscript below, which this score seems to follow faithfully:
 
The red box in the holograph snapshot is the SATB staves while the first 3 staves are for 2 violin + viola and the bottom staff is for double-bass + organ (written in figured-bass notation).  A typeset first edition published c. 1808 adds a Cembalo part (bottom staff below).

As to a theory of why / how the reduction/adaptation of your 1st image was made, please see @phoog's excellent answer which includes a comparison with historical editions.

But the edition shown in the question isn't identical to the keyboard reduction shown in this answer; see for example the following measure, where the keyboard reduction reflects the viola part while the edition in the question reflects the  hotel tenor part.

Or rather two measures later.

@phoog Thanks.  I updated my answer accordingly.
